# How can I copy a file to a memory if it has EOF as a content in C?

Tags: c, fonts

I am trying to copy a font file(.ttf) in C to a memory location. But the font file has FF as its content which is teh hex code for EOF. So, it is copying only till it encounters this character and then terminates. If I change the loop condition to the size of file and copy, the program hangs.

---

[update from comment:]

code:

```
do 
{ 
  a = fgetc(font); 
  memcpy(loadADD,&a,1); 
  i++; 
  loadADD++; 
} 
while (a != EOF); 
fclose(font);
```

Comment: Please show the code that's opening and reading the file.

Comment: @PaulRoub `code`  do
  {
      a = fgetc(font);
      memcpy(loadADD,&a,1);
      i++;
      loadADD++;      
   } while (a != EOF);
 
   fclose(font);

Comment: Please include the code *in the question*, and show the file being opened. Also, what type is `a`?

Comment: You might like to (re?-)read `fgets()` documentation and learn that `fget()` returns an `int`.

Comment: @PaulRoub I am really sorry. I am not allowed to do that as I am working on something confidential. Anyway, its a font file. .ttf

Comment: Please tell us how `a` is defined. Is it a `char` or an `int` or what else?

Comment: @alk it's almost certainly a `char` or `unsigned char`.  If it was an `int` he wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Sure, but the OP should mention this his/herself. However I tend to close this as being a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14235183/694576

Comment: @Prash An `fopen()` call is confidential? And the type of the `a` variable? You can change the filename, it's not exactly essential to solving the problem. Anyway, I do hope someone guesses the correct solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to distinguish between whatever function you're using returning the *signed* value -1 that is often used to indicate that there are no more characters to read, and the *unsigned values* from 0 .. 255 that represent the actual content of the file.

Since an `unsigned char` can only represent the latter range, it's common for `read` functions to use an `int` as their return value.  If the value is -1, that's an EOF, if it's 0 .. 255 then the result can be (safely) cast to an `unsigned char`, even if that value was `0xff`.

NB: strictly speaking the actual EOF character is 0x04 in ASCII.  It never actually appears in files as an EOF marker, although it used to be common in DOS systems for text files to end in a final `^Z` (0x1a) character, that being the DOS equivalent.

**EDIT** I see you're using `fgetc`.  This does indeed return an `int`, so you need to ensure that the return value is stored in an `int` before it's compared, but cast to an `unsigned char` before it's stored:

```
int a, i = 0;
while ((a = fgetc(font)) != EOF) {
    *loadAdd++ = (unsigned char)a;  // cast probably superfluous
    i++;
}
```

**EDIT2** for higher performance, but not particularly relevant to the original question:

```
int i = 0, n = 0;
while ((n = fread(loadAdd, 1, 4096, font)) > 0) {
    loadAdd += n;
    i += n;
}
```

NB: with either implementation you *must* ensure before hand that the memory buffer pointed to by the initial value of `loadAdd` is actually big enough to receive the entire file.

Comment: Oh but I tried it with -1 as well, doesn't change anything!

Comment: You don't show `a`, but I presume you've declared it as a `char`.  Don't - declare it as an `int` instead and then just say `*loadAdd = (unsigned char)a`.

Comment: @Prash oh, and `break` out of the loop as soon as you get the `EOF` - you don't need (or want) to store the `0xff` in the memory buffer.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently trying your code. Since, the file to be copied is 1MB, its taking a long time. Will let you know if it works. :)

Comment: @Prash a cleaner implementation would use `fread()` and get chunks of the file at a time instead of one byte at a time.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I will look up on fread.. But my problem is solved and thanks to you :)

Comment: @Prash please accept the answer (and upvote if you haven't already)